# What is bracketing?

Tags: exposure, terminology, bracketing

I have seen this term a lot and I was wondering what, in basic terms, what bracketing/autobracketing is.

Also, why would one want to 'bracket'?

*P.S. - there are other questions asking what DoF and WB bracketing is but none asking quite the same as this.*

Comment: It is in the tag wiki however, if you click on [bracketing].

Comment: @Mike I know, but I wanted a clearer, more detailed definition with reasons someone might use it for reference here on Photo.SE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### What is bracketing?

According to ['Bracketing' on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracketing),

> In photography, **bracketing** is the general technique of taking **several
> shots** of the same subject using **different camera settings**. Bracketing
> is useful and often recommended in situations that make it difficult
> to obtain a satisfactory image with a single shot, especially **when a
> small variation** in exposure parameters has a comparatively **large
> effect** on the resulting image.
>
> **Autobracketing** is **automatic bracketing**
> by using a setting on the camera to take several bracketed shots (in
> contrast to the photographer altering the settings by hand between
> each shot). Given the time it takes to accomplish multiple shots, it
> is typically, but not always, **used for static subjects**.

There are **6** main kinds of bracketing:

1. **Exposure Bracketing**
2. **Flash Bracketing**
3. **Depth of Field Bracketing**
4. **Focus Bracketing**
5. **White Balance Bracketing**
6. **ISO Bracketing**

When the general term 'bracketing' is used, however, it usually refers to **Exposure Bracketing**.

### What is it for?

The reasoning behind this is to be certain that you have taken the perfect shot; for example, when **Exposure Bracketing**, you will take three or more photos. At least one photo will be underexposed, at least one overexposed and one will be perfect.

### *Also: Exposure Fusion*

**Exposure Fusion** is the process of **fusing** together three or more photos at different exposures. This **is** a kind of HDR, despite what Mark Evans says in his otherwise good [DPS article](http://digital-photography-school.com/exposure-fusion-what-is-it-how-does-it-compare-to-hdr-how-do-i-do-it) also linked below (more info - [Comparison of HDR effects](http://cameradojo.com/2008/12/12/comparison-of-hdr-techniques/)).

[image]            [image]         [image]
[image]

*Photo with exposure fusion*

Learn more: [Digital Photography School](http://digital-photography-school.com/exposure-fusion-what-is-it-how-does-it-compare-to-hdr-how-do-i-do-it)

Comment: **Actually exposure Fusion *is* a kind of HDR photography if defined as *High Dynamic Range* Photography** that has been going on since 1850 when Gustave Le Gray combined two disparate exposures of a seascape. So was the dodging and burning that Ansell Adams elevated to an art form. *HDR is much broader than just 32-bit floating point digital images.*   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDR_photography

Comment: As many have pointed out in the comments of that DPS article, Mark Evans is incorrect that Exposure Fusion is not HDR.

Comment: There are *way* more types of bracketing than that! Check out any semi-advanced Nikon or Pentax DSLR and you'll find more options.

Answer (score 1):

Taking multiple pictures, often bursted, with (slightly) different settings. You could change the flash power, exposure, white balance, etc. Most cameras that are meant for photographic enthusiasts have this feature.

Bracketing could be a time saver and add convenience.