# Why are three nearly duplicate photos produced with Dynamic Range Optimization on a Sony SLT-A65V?

Tags: camera-settings, sony, bracketing

I have DRO turned on, and it gives me 3 slightly different photos of the same thing.

Now what?

1. Manually decide which is best?
2. Recombine them into a single better photo?  How?
3. Something else

End Goal

To have 1 copy of each image that takes advantage of DRO.

Comment: @PhilipKendall   Is that Long Exposure NR?  It must be called something else on my camera, where do I find it and/or what other alias could it be using?

Comment: hmm I found something under drive mode called bracketing, but I couldn't tell what it was set at.  I manually selected single mode, I guess testing is in order.

Comment: That must have been it, but I have no idea how it got turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three close to identical shots normally means that you have [exposure bracketing](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34941/what-is-bracketing) turned on. From [page 45 of the A65's manual](https://www.sony.co.uk/electronics/support/res/manuals/4287/42879531M.pdf), this is selected via the drive mode by pressing "Left" on the four-way controller and selecting either "C" (for exposure bracketing) or "WB" (for white balance bracketing).