# Does anyone know any app that can capture in raw multiple exposure value in a single capture?

Tags: hdr

I take photo from my android phone (Huawei P30 Pro) and I don't have tripod and my hands are unsteady.

When I took a photo manually and change the settings and then take another photo, the location slightly change, when I use programs to combine them in order to create hdr, some are blurry, most program that I use are a pain (I use Linux so i use programs that are on linux, kinda miss Lightroom BTW), I tried Hugin, Luminance HDR and HDRmerge, they are all blurry because i don't have steady hands, I want to know if there is any apps that you can preconfigure the settings that you want to use and when you click the shutter it will capture all the photos with different settings in one go (that would be a great tool for HDR lovers who want to have RAW files of all different pictures that are combined instead of only the result).

Most of my google search leads to burst mode, which did not answer my needs

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE! Please take moment to read the help section on [asking questions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you performed any websearches on this topic? What did you find? Could you please [edit] your question to show your research? Also on a light note: do you really want to [twerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twerking) the settings? ;)

Comment: If "When I took a photo manually" means you're using manual settings (overriding the phone's "auto" setting), then speed up the shutter to help eliminate the effects of your hands moving. Learn how to brace yourself to minimize movement. Lots of options to minimize/eliminate motion blur before the picture is taken. Also, yeah, no picture twerking, please!

Comment: oops, guess i use the wrong expression, i want to change the options to my liking as for my google search, i'll update it, but it has only burst mode and it is not what i look for

Comment: @FreeMan, yeah, that's not what I meant, maybe I wasn't clear enough, when I change the settings to take different exposure, and when I press the shutters, the position of the photo already change, even slightly, and the stitching programs are no help, changing the settings made the position change, I want something that I can take in one go and not have to change it each time and risking moving away from the original position, even in the slightest, that's the reason the result blurs, the program still have some way to go

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke seems like it, reading now, thx

Comment: Posting this question on Software Recommendations SE site might be more productive.

Comment: @EricS true, but the answer given are related to Photography SE, and i did learn something that are obtainable here, so i think it is appropriate as the answer given is here

Comment: I wanted to say tweaking, guess sometimes i confuse "a" and "r" lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you *are* actually looking for burst mode, but with the addition of [automatic bracketing](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/34941/9161).

An app that can do that would automatically take multiple frames quickly after each other, while changing the exposure slightly every frame. This will give you a burst of photos with different exposures which you can then merge.

However, even with bracketing there is an ever so slight delay between every frame. Shooting handheld will still result in changes in the framing. To do this effectively you probably need some form of a tripod.